# Nodemanger getting killed in Hadoop 2.6.0

Tags: hadoop

Before running a job all the daemons in slave nodes are working fine. But while executing a process, the NodeManger is getting killed in Hadoop 2.6.0

```
2014-07-20 05:16:00,568 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8031. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)

ERROR org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl: Unexpected error starting NodeStatusUpdater
java.net.ConnectException: Call From node06.nadcse.edu/172.16.6.129 to 0.0.0.0:8031 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Comment: There is nowhere near enough information here for anyone to be able to help you. Please show what you're doing, job logs, nodemanager logs etc.

Comment: I have shared the logs , initially the nodemanger is up and running but while executing a program it gets killed.

Answer (score 0):

> 0.0.0.0:8031

I would start looking at the problem from this part.
Address 0.0.0.0? Does not look right.
RM and NM assuming on different nodes. It wouldn't be to connect obviously.
If this is a test cluster or something like that, try changing yarn.nodemanager.hostname to 127.0.0.1.